# ERROR: column c.relhasoids does not exist at character 245 in PostgreSQL 13.2,

Tags: postgresql

I did upgrade from PostgreSQL 10 to PostgreSQL 13 and after that I am getting the following error in PostgreSQL log continuously.

> ERROR:  column c.relhasoids does not exist at character 245

Is there any way to fix?

Comment: You are still using software that is not compatible with Postgres 13 (e.g. an outdated JDBC driver or outdate SQL client tool)

Comment: Yes , I used lower version of psql odbc , now updated the the psqlodbc version 13 so issue fixed.